# Does Chinna Jeeyar have a scriptural basis for characterizing non-vegetarians the way he did?

Tags: diet, chinna-jeeyar

[https://thewire.in/caste/statue-politics-and-the-myth-of-ramanujas-equality#:~:text=Jeeyar%20said%20in%20one%20of%20his%20sermons%20just,dirt%2C%20place%20to%20place%2C%20and%20eat%20from%20it%E2%80%9D](https://thewire.in/caste/statue-politics-and-the-myth-of-ramanujas-equality#:%7E:text=Jeeyar%20said%20in%20one%20of%20his%20sermons%20just,dirt%2C%20place%20to%20place%2C%20and%20eat%20from%20it%E2%80%9D).

> Jeeyar said in one of his sermons just before the inauguration of the Statue of Equality:

> “If you eat pork, you would only think like a pig. If you eat mutton, you would only follow the herd like a goat as your own brain stops working. If you take eggs, you would only behave like a chicken – peck in the dirt, place to place, and eat from it”.

Here is the Telugu original:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X54sRZlNSWs

Is there scriptural basis to support Chinna Jeeyar's view of how diet affects personality?

Comment: Going by this logic Tigers and lions should behave like deer after eating them .. and dull humans should eat wise humans to up their IQ :banghead: